# Automated script to change default storage path in LibreOffice

Tags: path, storage, libreoffice

Hi Stackoverflow people,

LibreOffice's default storage path is located in `$USER/My Documents`.
It is easy to change this path in LibreOffice.

However, my employer has assigned me to reinstall 30 pc's with a linux distro. :)) 
All installations should include LibreOffice.

That is why I would like to run a automated post-install script which will change the default storage location in LibreOffice to a custom location on our company's document server.
e.g. "`LO_STORAGE_PATH = /mnt/documents`"
Reason: I think it is too time-consuming to change the storage path manually in LibreOffice on 30 pc's.

I tried searching with:
"Change storage path command LibreOffice"
"Script cli storage path LibreOffice"
"Bash change storage path LibreOffice"

Can anyone of you give me a hint?

Thanks!

Kees

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default save directory, you must edit Paths in LibreOffice. Usually, from the main menu *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths*, then edit the *My Documents* path value.

When doing that, the new value is saved in the file  `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`

And a new entry appears in this file like below :

```xml
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Paths/Paths/org.openoffice.Office.Paths:NamedPath['Work']"><prop oor:name="WritePath" oor:op="fuse"><value>$(work)/mynewpath</value></prop></item>
```

After some tests, this entry seams to allow only value starting with `$(work)`, the user home directory. By googlize, it may be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1085310).

With that you could be able to automate it with a *sed* expression.

If you search a more precise response, you can try to post your question to the dedicated forum http://ask.libreoffice.org/

Good luck